# Program method works syncrounously but exists with status code -1 for async counterpart

Tags: .net, async-await, rethinkdb, exit-code, reql

I am using rethinkdb and I am trying to delete all records in a table. The query works without problems when using the `Run` on the query , thus synchronously. When using the `RunAsync` the program exits with `status code -1`.

The program does not throw any exception so how am I supposed to find out why it exists?

```
public class ChangeFeedTests
{
    [TestCase()]
    public async Task ChangeFeedTest()
    {
       RethinkDB r = RethinkDB.R;  
       Connection.Builder builder = r.Connection();
       builder.Port(Constants.PORT).Hostname(Constants.HOST_NAME);
       Connection con = await builder.ConnectAsync(); /

           try
           {
               var c = await ret.Db(Constants.DB_NAME)
                                .Table(Constants.TABLE_NAME)
                                .Delete().RunAsync(conn); //->exits
                 //------------------.Run(conn)  -> works fine

           }
           catch (Exception ex)
           {

               throw;
           }



        Assert.IsTrue(true);

    }
}
```

Comment: What is the purpose for having the delegate in the first place. You could have called kept the test async all the way through. By using the action you have an async void which wont allow you catch any of the exceptions.

Comment: I edited the post.

Comment: does the test runner get the error message?

Comment: I am not at my pc at the moment but the only thing that i was seeing is in the `Output` section `program exited with status code -1`.

Answer (score 0):

You could have called kept the test async all the way through.

By using the `Action` you have an `async void` which wont allow you to catch any of the exceptions.

```
[TestCase()]
public async Task ChangeFeedTest() {
    //Arrange
    RethinkDB rethinkDb = RethinkDB.R;
    Connection connection = await rethinkDb.Connection()
        .Port(Constants.PORT)
        .Hostname(Constants.HOST_NAME)
        .ConnectAsync();

    //Act
    var actual = await rethinkDb.Db(Constants.DB_NAME).Table(Constants.TABLE_NAME)
                        .Delete().RunAsync(connection);

    //Assert

    //...do assertions here
}
```

So now any exception thrown would be caught by the test runner and displayed in the test results.

Reference [Async/Await - Best Practices in Asynchronous Programming](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx)

Comment: Long story short i need the the `Func`(it would wrap a `Task ` for parallel execution.The point i am trying to make is that the same behaviour happens when i run the code free of delegates.

Comment: I cut alot of the method i should have cut the delegate part too its irrelevant for the probelem.

Comment: I edited the post , it does exit with status code -1 even without delegates on async call.